# How does non-constant conductivity change surface charge on a wire?

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, electric-current

Current density is equal to conductivity times electric field. Therefore flux through a cross section of a wire is equal to current over conductivity. Current has to be constant along a wire. This means that as conductivity along a wire increases, flux through a cross section decreases. In equations:

Flux = Current/Conductivity

This seems to mean that the flux difference is made up by charges in or on the wire. In particular, by Gauss's law the charge on a section of wire with conductivity changing from A to B is:

Current/B - Current/A = q/e0

Is this accurate? Does this mean that high charges can be concentrated by running current through a wire with rapidly changing conductivity? Or is something else going on?